# PHP Ajax pagination array not working

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, arrays, pagination

I am using the following code for pagination with ajax and php.

fetch_pages.php

```
<?php

include("config.inc.php"); //include config file

//sanitize post value
$page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

//validate page number is really numaric
if(!is_numeric($page_number)){die('Invalid page number!');}

//get current starting point of records
$position = ($page_number * $item_per_page);

//Limit our results within a specified range. 
//$results = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT id,name,message FROM paginate ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $position, $item_per_page");
$results=array(array('id'=>1,'name'=>'joe','age'=>'22','job'=>'dev'),array('id'=>2,'name'=>'g','age'=>'21','job'=>'se'),array('id'=>3,'name'=>'gt','age'=>'21','job'=>'se'));
$output = array_slice($results, 0,1); 
//output results from database
echo '<ul class="page_result">';
//while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
foreach ($output as $row) 

{
    echo '<li id="item_'.$row["name"].'">'.$row["age"].'. <span class="page_name">'.$row["job"].'</span><span class="page_message">'.$row["name"].'</span></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';

?>
```

index.php

```
  <?php
include("config.inc.php");

//$results = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM paginate");
$results=array(array('id'=>1,'name'=>'joe','age'=>'22','job'=>'dev'),array('id'=>2,'name'=>'g','age'=>'21','job'=>'se'),array('id'=>3,'name'=>'gt','age'=>'21','job'=>'se'));
//$get_total_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results); //total records

//break total records into pages
//$pages = ceil($get_total_rows[0]/$item_per_page); 
$pages = ceil(3/$item_per_page);    

//create pagination
if($pages > 1)
{
    $pagination = '';
    $pagination .= '<ul class="paginate">';
    for($i = 1; $i<$pages; $i++)
    {
        $pagination .= '<li><a href="#" class="paginate_click" id="'.$i.'-page">'.$i.'</a></li>';
    }
    $pagination .= '</ul>';
}

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Ajax Pagination</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php", {'page':0}, function() {$("#1-page").addClass('active');});  //initial page number to load

    $(".paginate_click").click(function (e) {

        $("#results").prepend('<div class="loading-indication"><img src="ajax-loader.gif" /> Loading...</div>');

        var clicked_id = $(this).attr("id").split("-"); //ID of clicked element, split() to get page number.
        var page_num = parseInt(clicked_id[0]); //clicked_id[0] holds the page number we need 

        $('.paginate_click').removeClass('active'); //remove any active class

        //post page number and load returned data into result element
        //notice (page_num-1), subtract 1 to get actual starting point
        $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php", {'page':(page_num-1)}, function(){

        });

        $(this).addClass('active'); //add active class to currently clicked element (style purpose)

        return false; //prevent going to herf link
    }); 
});
</script>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="results"></div>
<?php echo $pagination; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the data source for this to be an array defined in the code, not a mysql database therefore you will see `$results=array(array('name'=>'gowrie','age'=>'22','job'=>'dev'),array('name'=>'g','age'=>'21','job'=>'se'));` instead of a mysql query.

In fetchespages.php there should be a query `$results = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT id,name,message FROM paginate ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $position, $item_per_page");`, that would limit the result for the page, however I replaced it with `$results=array(array('name'=>'joe','age'=>'22','job'=>'dev'),array('name'=>'g','age'=>'21','job'=>'se'));`

The page shows the correct number of pagination links, but when I click them, they don't work, it just keeps loading. I'm not sure if it's a problem with my ajax in index.php or the way I attempt to limit results in the array in fetch_pages.php, ie `$output = array_slice($results, 0,1);` WHn I click the pagination links, it loads the same thing on the page.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you use

> $output = array_slice($results, 0,1);

the array is always limited to the first key=>value pair no matter which page link you click. Just like in the sql query, where you use limit and position/items per page, you'll have to do the same with your slice function. so it becomes something like

```
$output = array_slice($results, $position, $items_per_page);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: its an effect of just copying a code block and not using indent properly

Comment: @Jonast92 Now that the answer at least makes *some* kind of sense I have removed the downvote.  As for the "moves forward", I'm not sure what is meant there.  Perhaps criticism for my downvote?  The original answer made absolutely no sense and was unintelligible.  Can you really blame me?

Comment: @MatthewJohnson Not at all, just wanted to point out his fix since it seemed to be your only reason for down-voting, I don't have anything else to say about his answer since I'm not interested in the question :)

Comment: "Now that the answer at least makes some kind of sense" - that comment is not worthy. The block of code I mention is definitely braking the code in the example, thus I think my answer does help partially, to resolve the problem.